# Use CouchDB with Node.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchapp, commonjs

CouchDB uses javascript to validate, query, do map-reduce and so on. I'd like to know is there any way to use `node.js` library in these javascript functions? Such as use `require('http')` or some third party modules installed with `npm`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node.js libraries as long as they don't require Node.js-specific libraries like `http`. For example, [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) works in CouchDB. Rule of thumb: if it's intended for the server *and* the client, you should be good.

You can use CommonJS's `module.exports` and `exports[something]` patterns to share code between views. Check out [the documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules) for more details.

For example, consider this view:

```
{
  _id:"_design/test",
  views: {
    lib: {
      test: "exports.guests = 42;"
    },
    fish_per_person: {
      map: function(doc){
        var guests = require('views/lib/test').guests; // 42
        emit(doc.number_of_fish, doc.number_of_fish / guests);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `fish_per_person` view requires the value `guests` exported in `lib/test`.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I will need these libraries.

Comment: Which libraries? What are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like a challenge and I'm very interested.

Comment: There is no specific thing for me to accomplish now. But I can image some. For example, if I'm working on a [online judge system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_judge), after user submit code, I need use `child_process` to compile and run it in the CouchDB update handler.

Comment: Clever! I'll propose that use case at Cloudant and see what we can do. 

On the other hand, doing that in the app layer isn't hard. Watch the _changes feed for your database from a Node.js process, and react to relevant changes as they come through the feed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to use external JavaScript from a Node module inside of CouchDb. You can do some limited sharing: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Sharing_Code_Between_Views

Node is a platform that is exposed to a Javascript language binding, so the "goodness" of Node is in the execution environment.

And while there is a way to write Views using Python, I'm not aware of anything similar for Node.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that CouchDB currently uses Mozilla's SpiderMonkey JS engine for execution. However, it has been discussed on the CouchDB mailing list about replacing that with Node.js, which would allow for using NPM modules within CouchDB. (but that is a long ways off)

Comment: Interesting find. For production use? No, I wouldn't use it. Also, as node is single threaded, you'd be funneling everything down a single path.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I find [an article](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server). In fact, I can use any language to write a view server. It use stdin/stdout to communicate. So I think there will be a split process start while query the view server. Would you think it could be used in the production environment?

Comment: He many points of failure do you want? Nodejs also hasn't reached 1.0.